# String and imag array random in NetBeans?

Tags: java, string, random, netbeans-7

How can I generate a String and an image array in NetBeans? I try to make the arrays like

```
string{"lion","cat","dog","bird"};
```

How can I use the Random class to get `s[i]` where `i` is random?

Comment: We cannot see your set-up -- we don't know what the images are or where they are or what format they are. Please provide more information on image / photo array. We are willing to help, but as such, in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

`String [] animals = {"lion","cat","dog","bird"};
int rndindex = (int)(Math.random()*number_of_element);
String rndAnimal = animals[rndIndex];`

Make the array, get a random number between 0 and n inclusively where n is the number of elements in the array. Then retrieve that element.

Answer (score 1):

```
java.util.Random rand = new java.util.Random();
int index = rand.nextInt(4);
System.out.println(string[index]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, one solution is to use [`Collections.shuffle(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29). I know, you wanted to do it with a `String[]` bute we can use [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) and use the fact that this `List<String>` is backed by a `String[]` like so,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] animals = { "lion", "cat", "dog", "bird" };
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(animals));
  Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(animals));
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(animals));
}
```

Output is

```
[lion, cat, dog, bird]
[cat, lion, dog, bird]
```

**Edit**

If you just want one element at a random position in the array, that would be

```
String[] animals = { "lion", "cat", "dog", "bird" };
System.out.println(animals[rand.nextInt(animals.length)]);
```

Comment: String[] r = {...} -- he wants r[i] a single element.

Comment: one photo from photos array and user will enter the name in textfield how?

Comment: @user3784250 Create one object holding an animal name and a photo, and then use an array of the object. Then you can use my first example to shuffle your array. Also, what textfield?

Comment: import javax.swing.jtexfiled;

Comment: @Eric Edited, in case you are correct.

Comment: @user3784250 Your question doesn't mention it.